# Prove that when the algorithm terminates, V' is non-empty.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given graph G = (V, E) and any subset of vertices V' $\subseteq$ V, I define the induced graph G[V'] to the graph whose vertex set is V', and whose edges are E' = {(u, v) $\in$ E | u $\in$ V and v $\in$ V}. In words, G' is the graph G restricted only to vertices/edges in V'.

Claim: Consider any unweighted, undirected graph G = (V, E) with |V| = n and |E| = m. If m $\geq$ $100n^{5/4}$ then there exists a set V' $\subseteq$ V such that every vertex in G[V'] has degree at least $3n^{1/4}$ in G[V']. Note that I am considering the degree in G[V'], not in the original graph G. Formally, every vertex v $\in$ V' must have at least $3n^{1/4}$ neighbors in V'; that is, there must be at least $3n^{1/4}$ vertices x $\in$ V' such that edge (v, x) $\in$ E.

This was proved by explicitly giving a procedure for constructing V'.

1. Start with V' $\leftarrow$ V
2. While there exists v $\in$ V' with [degree of v in G[V']] < $3n^{1/4}$

   ```
           remove v from V'
   ```
3. return V'

What I have to do is prove that when the above procedure terminates, V' is non-empty.

What I was confused about is that even if a vertex v initially has degree  $\geq$ $3n^{1/4}$ in V, as we start removing from V', [degree of v in V'] will drop. So, in theory, I feel as though it is possible that we will end up removing all vertices using the procedure above. However, that does not end up happening and I am confused as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have at least $200n^{5/4}$ edge ends divided up over $n$ vertices, the average degree of a vertex in $G$ is at least $200n^{1/4}$. If you remove $k$ vertices of degree $\le 3n^{-1/4}$ or less, then at most you remove $6kn^{1/4}$ edge ends. So the average degree of the remaining vertices will be at least
$$\dfrac{200n^{5/4}-6k\cdot n^{1/4}}{n-k}\ge \dfrac{200n^{5/4}-6n\cdot n^{1/4}}{n}=194n^{1/4} > 3n^{1/4}$$

No matter how many vertices you remove, the average degree of the remaining vertices is much greater than $3n^{1/4}$. There will always be some vertices of higher degree remaining. Even if you allow loops in your graph, that last vertex will have degree much higher than $3n^{1/4}$ and therefore will not be removable.